# How do I keep passwords out of publicly visible code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app I'm trying to deploy and something is concerning me about security. Is there a way to avoid storing my e-mail password in plain text in setup_mail, and my database passwords in environment.rb?

Comment: **Very** similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290/how-do-you-secure-database-yml

Comment: I dunno what mechanism you are using for your authentication system. In devise authentication mechanisms they automatically store the passwords in a encrypted format.  "t.string   "encrypted_password",    t.string   "password_salt","

Comment: Zabba - similar yes, but not identical. That question is at least somewhat framed in relation to Capistrano and I am not using Capistrano at all (this is deploying on Heroku). Plus, I'm asking about files other than just database.yml. If these amount to the same thing then fine but the identity is not automatically self-evident.

Comment: @Saran - I'm using AuthLogic and I have all passwords blocked from the log files (and of course, stored encrypted in the database). My concern is more with passwords stored in the app's setup files like passwords for e-mail accounts and the database.

Answer (score 4):

You can store the passwords as a file on your deployment server and then have something along the lines of this in database.yml (or wherever else you have sensitive data):

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  host: localhost
  database: foobar_production
  username: foobar
  password: <%= begin IO.read("/home/deploy/passwords/foobar.db") rescue "" end %>
```

... where foobar.db is a plaintext file containing just the password.

Comment: Ensure that access to the file is locked down.

Comment: @Preet: How would you do that?

Comment: it's all dependent on the OS.

Comment: I agree with this concept. The way that I do it is to use capistrano. I have the password file on the server in `~/apps/<appname>/shared/config/database.yml` and setup a custom deploy task to copy or symlink the file from there to `~/apps/<appname>/current/config/database.yml`, this way your production passwords are never in your code repo, or any other machine.